# Как сделать аналог collapse из bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Есть задача сделать collapse при этом не подтягивая какие-либо большие зависимости. Решил быстро написать свое решение на основе такового в bootstrap. Однако, не тут-то было. Я не понимаю почему, но после того, как я полностью воспроизвел все поведение bootstrap у себя в коде, мой collapse все еще не работает должным образом.

Вот целевая страница на [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/). В качестве примера взял первый же collapse.

Его алгоритм для открытия таков:

1. По умолчанию целевой элемент имеет класс collapse (display: none)
2. После клика на кнопку в целевом элементе удаляется класс collapse и устанавливается класс collapsing. Параллельно с этим через js устанавливается css свойство height на высоту целевого контента. Из-за transition свойства в классе collapsing это все происходит анимировано.
3. По окончании анимации у целевого элемента удаляется класс collapsing и устанавливаются классы collapse и show (display: block). Атрибут style полностью очищается.

Этот сценарий у меня отрабатывает, хорошо. Но вот закрытие на работает анимировано, а происходит резко. Алгоритм закрытия следующий:

1. Удаляются классы collapse и show, устанавливается класс collapsing
2. После окончания анимации удаляется класс collapsing и устанавливается класс collapse.

На сайте bootstrap все работает идеально, у меня же, как я подозреваю, не срабатывает свойство transition и я РЕШИТЕЛЬНО не понимаю почему. css код всех трех нужных классов я скопировал в точности с сайта bootstrap. JS же код в точности повторяет алгоритм действий, который я описал выше. Ошибок быть не может, я множество раз через консоль гугла сравнивал поведение dom элементов моего решения и решения bootstrap. Все в точности точно также, однако у них закрытие хорошо анимировано, а у меня нет.

```
UPDATE: Я воспроизвел проблему в песочнице. Можете глянуть код, сравнить 
с тем, как работает в bootstrap и сказать где я ошибся. 

https://jsfiddle.net/eo83h15s/1/
```

```js
const target = document.querySelector('.target')
const content = document.querySelector('.content')
let isOpen = isOpenCollapse()

function toggleCollapse() {
  isOpen = isOpenCollapse()
  target.classList.remove('collapse', 'show')
  target.classList.add('collapsing')

  if (isOpen) {
    target.style.height = content.offsetHeight + 'px'
  }

  setTimeout(transitionEnd, 1000)
}

function transitionEnd() {
  target.classList.remove('collapsing')
  target.classList.add('collapse')
  target.setAttribute('style', '')

  if (isOpen) {
    target.classList.add('show')
  }
}

function isOpenCollapse() {
  return target.classList.contains('collapse') && !target.classList.contains('show')
}
```

```css
.collapse {
  display: none;
}

.collapse.show {
  display: block;
}

.collapsing {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleCollapse()">Клик</button>

<div class="target collapse show">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Тест</h1>
    <h1>Тест</h1>
    <h1>Тест</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А пробовали вместо `height` анимировать `max-height` ?)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, ваш совет из разряда "перезагрузи компьютер". Нет, работает точно также, как и просто с высотой. Глупо полагать, что проблема в этом, учитывая, что в bootstrap прекрасно работает просто с height. А вопрос как раз и состоит в том, почему у них работает, а у меня нет. При чем не работает у меня анимировано только закрытие, что явно указывает на проблемы со свойством transition.

Comment: Мне кажется, что у вас в примере каша :) Мой совет - представьте себе, как оно должно работать, по шагам. Открытие, закрытие. Назовите нормально классы. Продумайте ваши шаги. Сейчас в вашем примере нету какой-то одной ошибки - весь код работает неправильно)

Comment: Я потратил некоторое количество времени, пытаясь исправить ваш код с минимальными изменениями и что бы он работал. И пришел к выводу, что это невозможно, т.к. ваш код работает абсолютно неправильно. Дело не оформлении кода, а в логике его работы. Пожалуйста, не переходите на личности.

Comment: Спасибо, я попросил не переходить на личности, но видимо вы это проигнорировали. Удачи.

Comment: @StepanK, ну а как еще реагировать? Я четко описал проблему и даже знаю с чем связана ошибка и дал это понять в вопросе. В скрипте же я реализовал точь в точь то, что описал в проблеме. И тут вы приходите и говорите, что скрипт работает неправильно без всяких наводок, хотя он делает ровно то, что я описал. Проблема в самом алгоритме, я упустил какое-ту важную особенность браузера или пропустил важный шаг из-за которого не работает. Ответы из разряда "оно не работает" при такой детализации в описании - это последнее, что мне нужно было. Я на полном серьезе думал, что вы бот.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Я слишком сильно полагался на инспектор браузера в надежде, что он правильно успевал отображать мне все изменения dom дерева.

В поисках истины я нехотя заглянул в исходный код bootstrap и обнаружил, что для корректной анимации они перед установкой класса collapsing и сразу после этого буквально на несколько тиков времени явно устанавливают высоту целевому блоку, чтобы свойство transition знало что ему анимировать.

UPDATE: Заметил, что я не уточнил, что для того, чтобы transition засчитало вашу двойную смену высоты не атомарной операцией и от этого был толк, то вторую смену высоты нужно заключить в функцию setTimeout без указания времени, чтобы инструкция была исполнена в следующем цикле событий. Ниже прикреплю полностью работающий пример кода.

```
Пример кода:
https://jsfiddle.net/8ogm3djz/3/
```